# NLTK install regarding sentiment analyzer

Tags: nltk

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sentiments = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
```

The above code is the thing I need to install sentiment vader but it shows look up error

so I tried this command

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

while using the above command it shows an error regarding error connecting to server, tried all possible ways, I need to install but nothing works out. The image is attached down

[image]